# Vue JS - How do I get a route (:id) into an i18N translation?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vue-i18n

Imagine this Vue JS template:

```
<template>
    <b-container>
      <b-row>
        <b-col>
          <div>
          {{$t("competence.*web-developer*.title1")}}
          </div>
        </b-col>
      </b-row>
  </b-container>
</template>
```

Now imagine '*web-developer*' is the route id.

The route works fine.

```
const routes = [
{ path: '/competences/:id', name: Competences, component: Competences, props: true }
```

];

My question: how can I get {{this.$route.params.id}} into my translation like this...

```
{{$t("competence.{{this.$route.params.id}}.title1")}}
```

I realise I can't do this, but this is what I'm trying to achieve. What's the best way to handle a dynamic value in a translation string?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can concatenate string in template.

```
{{$t("competence."+$route.params.id+".title1")}}
```

Comment: Super, that's it. Obviously! I wasn't seeing it, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you could navigate between routes using the name attr and filing the path parameter with the internationalised value. that way you can pass anything in the path.